# Patch for device tree

Tags: yocto, patch

I am trying to configure and update my device tree by adding a node to it using a patch file created using quilt and building it with yocto.
made the bbappend recipe of the one already present in the BSP layer of the kernel directory.
patches are getting compiled but failing to update the source code and the node I am trying to create on my board is not reflected running kernel.

```
#this recipe is used to modify the kernel files

DESCRIPTION = "Patch file for kernel"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI_append = " \
         file://001-adding-headers-msm8909-mdss-panels-dtsi.patch       \
         file://001-SPI3-Node-msm8909-pinctrl-dtsi.patch                \
         file://001-adding-node-to-config-msm8909-dtsi.patch            \
         file://001-spi0-i2c-node-msm8909-mtp-dtsi.patch                \
        "
```

whereas patch files also point to the exact source code I am trying to modify.

What is the area I am missing over it? The data I am trying to add with help of a patch is working fine if I directly paste it to the source code of the device tree. but trying to add it with help of a patch because not want to modify BSP-layer doing the changes within my local layer.

Comment: What is the error ? Did you create the patch directly from the folder of the device tree ?

Comment: There is no error build successful, you can have a look at the build log at "https://docs.google.com/document/d/154JX1k8VKWPKvx8bIrVT5eAh4fYlcagHcPiSBe46TS4/edit?usp=sharing"
But the Modified node of the device tree is not reflected after the build

Comment: Try to debug the build using bitbake virtual/kernel -vvv -D then you have much more information about what happened. also try to work according https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/index.html